# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' for gradle version 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains more than one file.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

Comment: Do you have android studio installed in your machine?

Comment: yes @Parth android studio is installed.

Answer (score 1):

1)Clean and Rebuild project should work. It works for me

2)Try: invalidate caches/Restart